# Incorrect behaviour when clicking on a Button

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm facing an issue when I click on some buttons in a web application I'm currently developing. So, after the first click, the button lose its position in the layout, then after another click or interaction with an element it moves to the correct position.

I'm using material-ui Grid system to make the layout responsive. Grid's breakpoints should be working, but it doesn't. I've already set lg, md, sm to 12. One way to make it work as intended is to set an inline style for the parent element. After setting its width to 100%, it works, but I want to use material-ui grid sizing.

"Actions" is a styled-components wrapper.

```
<Grid container item direction="column">
  //...other grid items//
  <Grid item lg={12} md={12} xs={12} /* style={{ width: '100%' }} */>
     <Actions>
       <Button variant={'contained'} color={'primary'} onClick={onSave} disabled={btnLoading}>
        { btnLoading && <Icon type={'loading'} /> }
                Salvar
        </Button>
     </Actions>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I expect the button to keep intended positioning on the right. Here is a GIF I made showing the issue.

https://share.getcloudapp.com/7Ku2GLxw

Comment: Have you used the browser DOM inspect tool to see what CSS is being applied against it in both cases?

Comment: @DrewReese, yes. CSS-wise it doesn't change, just visually.

Comment: Sorry, should have also asked you to check that other non-visible elements are not getting inserted into the DOM or changing that would cause the layout to change and push the button to the right.

Comment: @DrewReese, no element is inserted into the DOM. What is very unusual is that onClick method isn't called when I click for the very first time on the button (just before the issue happens).